# Is it possible to set a boolean-value claims in your Identity Token with Duende Identity Server 5?

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server, identityserver5

I'm trying to set a custom claim with some code for Duende Identity Server 5.2.3.

The claim works / is added, but it's a string and not a boolean.
I've notied -another- claim inthe JWT that *is a boolean* so I'm wondering, can I do this also?

Here's the code and then the sample JWT:

```
public class CustomTokenService : DefaultTokenService
{
    public override async Task<Token> CreateIdentityTokenAsync(TokenCreationRequest request)
    {
        var token = await base.CreateIdentityTokenAsync(request);

        bool isThisInAGracePeriod = true; // for example ...

        // This doesn't work. There's no bool overload, for the 2nd argument.
        // var myClaim = new Claims("in_grace_period", isThisInAGracePeriod);

        // I need to convert the bool to a string, using ToString();
        var myClaim = new Claims("in_grace_period", isThisInAGracePeriod.ToString());

        token.Claims.Add(myClaim);
    }
}
```

[image]

so notice:

- `email_verified` is a `bool` value
- `in_grace_period` is a `string` value (because I had to `ToString()` it :(  )

Is it possible to add my custom claim as a `bool` so it ends up looking like how `email_verified` is serialized out to the token payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Claim` class has a constructor that accepts 3 parameters and the 3rd one is value type.

```
var claim = new Claim(
    type: "in_grace_period", 
    value: isThisInAGracePeriod.ToString().ToLower(),
    valueType: ClaimValueTypes.Boolean);
```